# Simplify check to show selected control

Tags: c#, switch-statement

So I have this code. What it does is to show the selected usercontrol when user tap a button. If that particular usercontrol is already visible, tapping its button will hide it.

The code is rather repetitive, any suggestion how can I make it more succinct?

```
private void changeControl(TextControl control)
    {
        switch (control)
        {
            case TextControl.TextBox:

                if (IsRadTextBoxVisible == true)
                {
                    IsRadTextBoxVisible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    IsRadTextBoxVisible = true;
                }

                IsCountriesListBoxVisible = false;
                IsSliderFontSizeVisible = false;
                IsSliderFontRotateVisible = false;
                break;

            case TextControl.Font:

                if (IsCountriesListBoxVisible == true)
                {
                    IsCountriesListBoxVisible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    IsCountriesListBoxVisible = true;
                }

                IsRadTextBoxVisible = false;
                IsSliderFontSizeVisible = false;
                IsSliderFontRotateVisible = false;    
                break;

            case TextControl.Size:

                if (IsSliderFontSizeVisible == true)
                {
                    IsSliderFontSizeVisible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    IsSliderFontSizeVisible = true;
                }

                IsRadTextBoxVisible = false;
                IsCountriesListBoxVisible = false;
                IsSliderFontRotateVisible = false;             
                break;

            case TextControl.Rotate:

                if (IsSliderFontRotateVisible == true)
                {
                    IsSliderFontRotateVisible = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    IsSliderFontRotateVisible = true;
                }

                IsRadTextBoxVisible = false;
                IsCountriesListBoxVisible = false;
                IsSliderFontSizeVisible = false;

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void changeControl(TextControl control)
    {
        IsRadTextBoxVisible = control == TextControl.TextBox ? !IsRadTextBoxVisible : false;
        IsCountriesListBoxVisible = control == TextControl.Font ? !IsCountriesListBoxVisible : false;
        IsSliderFontSizeVisible = control == TextControl.Size ? !IsSliderFontSizeVisible : false;
        IsSliderFontRotateVisible = control == TextControl.Rotate ? !IsSliderFontRotateVisible : false;
    }
```

What it does:

```
control == TextControl.TextBox
```

returns either true or false.

Now, [ternary operator ?:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) executes code after **?** if expression before **?** returned true,
or code after **:** if expression before **?** returned false

In this case, if **control** matches, we're executing code after **?**, which in this case toggles the property.
If we **control** doesn't match, we're executing code after **:**, which sets the property to false.

Answer (score 1):

```
var stateRad= IsRadTextBoxVisible;
var stateSlider = IsSliderFontRotateVisible;
var ........
var ........

IsCountriesListBoxVisible = false;
IsSliderFontSizeVisible = false;
IsSliderFontRotateVisible = false;
IsRadTextBoxVisible = false
switch (control)
{
    case TextControl.TextBox:
        IsRadTextBoxVisible = !stateRad
        break;

    case TextControl.Font:
        IsCountriesListBoxVisible = !statexxx
        break;

    case TextControl.Size:
        IsSliderFontSizeVisible = !statexxx
        break;

    case TextControl.Rotate:
        IsSliderFontRotateVisible = !statexxx
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this does not hide the control when it's already visible because that control is set to invisible in the beginning.

Comment: oh. save these controls's state to var, then !var in switch block

Comment: The best way is define the dictionary with IsXXXVisible Property and TextControl.

Answer (score 0):

I such cases i would not use switch-case, becuase you can't make complex boolean-operations. Maybe you can make your code more efficent with some if-else statements. Switch-Cases are some times very limited and would not use them.